# NameError for urllib

Tags: python, shell

When I type `dir(urllib)` in the Python shell I get `NameError: Name urllib not defined`.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, you have to `import urllib` first. Try this one by one:

```
import urllib

dir(urllib)
```